# If String in Java is of final Class then how come we change the value of it?

Tags: java

Even though `String` is a `final` class we can change the value of it like:

```
String A = "hello";
```

And in next step:

```
A = "World";
```

Here `A` will be changed.

Whereas in case of a final variable we can't do it like:

```
final int a =10;
a = 13; //This Will Give Error
```

This would be a contradiction.

Comment: final class and final variable are different things.

Comment: "Please Ans as Soon as possible." [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when the class is final it means the methods of the class cannot be changed or overridden. If a field is final, then the value cannot be changed after the initial value has been assigned.

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify a bit the first part of your answer.